# AWS Glue job executors dying during shuffle write operations (writing parquets to S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm currently experiencing some issues with an **AWS Glue Job** that does some Spark SQL left joins of various datasets, and some help would be appreciated to understand the cause.

The issue:

The Glue Job does some Spark SQL processing (several left joins) and then a SinkDataFrametoS3 functions gets called (sinks parquet files to S3 output folder).

However once the job gets to the sinking dataframe part, executors start to fail and the job fails with failedtofetchmetadata errors and shuffle related messages.

It appears that there's big shuffle write operations going on (original datasets combined are less than 15GB altogether, but the shuffle is over 80GB at some point in write) right before these executors die.

What I have tried to solve the issue:

- I have tried messing with the configuration of the Scala job executed in Glue but no success,

```
val confParams: List[(String, String)] = List(
      "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" -> "2000", // I have tried all sorts of value from 100 to 10000 in intervals
      "spark.default.parallelism" -> "2000" // same as above
    )
```

- I have checked the spark UI history, confirming an issue in the shuffle write, but no luck figuring out what to do.
- I have changed the amount of DPUs and type of Spark workers to G.2X, but other than using up more money there seems to be no change/improvement

SinkDataFrameToS3 code:

```
 def sinkDataFrameToS3(glueContext: GlueContext, df: DataFrame, s3Path: String, fileFormat: String = "glueparquet", partitionKeys: Seq[String] = Seq()) = {
    if (df.isEmpty) {
      logger.warn("DataFrame empty - Nothing to sink")
    } else {
      var sinkOptions: Map[String, Any] = Map("path" -> s3Path)
      if (partitionKeys.nonEmpty) sinkOptions += ("partitionKeys" -> partitionKeys)

      logger.info("Sinking dataframe to s3...")
      glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(
        "s3",
        JsonOptions(sinkOptions),
        "",
        fileFormat
      ).writeDynamicFrame(DynamicFrame.apply(df, glueContext))
    }
  }
```

[Spark UI History (Executors)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l6m3.jpg)
[Spark UI History (Stages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLsl2.png)

Thanks in advance for any pointers as to how to attack this next.

Comment: Try to switch from glue 4 to glue 3. Had something similar and that was the only solution to fix my job.